# Parsing quoted CSVs with CHCSVParser

Tags: ios, csv

I'm using CHCSVParser to parse a CSV on an iPhone.  If I don't wraps the fields in the CSV it works fine.  Except that I then can't use commas in the fields!  But if I use quotes it doesn't import anything.
Example CSV that fails:

```
"Myotis", "distribution-myotis.png", "myotis description"
"Bbar", "bbar-distribution.png", "bbar description"
"Lesser Horseshoe", "distribution-lesser-horsehoe.jpg", "LH description"
```

Code:

```
NSString *CSVfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
CSVfile = [CSVfile stringByAppendingString:@"/batDB.csv"];
_batDB = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:CSVfile options:CHCSVParserOptionsSanitizesFields];
NSLog(@"%@", _batDB);
```

This logs null.  Without the quotes it correctly logs the contents on the CSV file in the array.

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 1):

Sigh....solved it with trial and error, I have an extra space after the comma.  i.e. `", "` rather than `","`

Comment: Interesting, I'm not sure that should make a difference.  Please open a new issue on Github and I'll look in to it.